# comparing strings by lexicographical order in e/specman

Tags: specman, e

Does specman have something like lex_lt(s1,s2) methods? (i.e. compare strings by lexicographical order). If not, is there a recommended way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there isn't. You can do 2 things here. You can either implement your own `strcmp()` style function in `e` and use that directly, or you can integrate Specman with a C file that wraps `strcmp()` in function that can be called from your `e` code. Have a look at the `Specman Integrator's Guide` section in the product manual for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we don’t have something pre-defined for this.
But it can be done, for example, in the following ugly way:

if {s1;s2}.sort(it)[0] == s1 ….    // if it’s TRUE, then s1 is less that s2, otherwise not

Of course, as Tudor suggested, the best way will be to define C routine to wrap strcmp().